# PMF of arg min of exponential random variables

Tags: random-variables, exponential-distribution

I am trying to find the pmf of a random variable of arg min of a sequence of independent exponential random variables i.e., $X_i = exp(\lambda_i)$.

Let L be a random variable defined by $$L = {arg min}_{1≤i≤n}X_i$$

That is, L = k if ${X}_{k}$ happens to be the minimum among $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$. I am interested in finding the pmf of L.

I am arriving at $\frac{\lambda_k} {\sum_{i=1}^n{\lambda_i}}$ as the PMF, where $\lambda_i$ is the exponential distribution parameter of $X_i$. I am trying to validate my answer here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE ! Are the $X_i$ independent ? Can you share in more details how you got your result ?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, the $X_i$s are indpendent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume $\lambda_i$ is a rate parameter, i.e. $$\Pr[X_i \le x] = 1 - e^{-\lambda_i x}, \quad x \ge 0.$$
Let $\Lambda = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i$ be the sum of rates, and for the sake of convenience, let $\Lambda_k = -\lambda_k + \Lambda$; i.e., $\Lambda_k$ is the sum of all rates except the $k^{\rm th}$ rate.  Then we observe that $$\prod_{i = 1 \\ i \ne k}^n \Pr[X_i \ge x]  = e^{-\Lambda_k x}.$$

Because the $X_i$ are independent,
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[L = k] &= \int_{x=0}^\infty \Pr[L = k \mid X_k = x]f_{X_k}(x) \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=0}^\infty \left(\prod_{i \ne k} \Pr[X_i \ge x]\right)f_{X_k}(x) \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=0}^\infty e^{-\Lambda_k x} \lambda_k e^{-\lambda_k x} \, dx \\
&= \lambda_k \int_{x=0}^\infty e^{-\Lambda x} \, dx \\
&= \frac{\lambda_k}{\Lambda} \int_{x=0}^\infty \Lambda e^{-\Lambda x} \, dx \\
&= \frac{\lambda_k}{\Lambda},
\end{align}$$
which completes the proof.